# What's on the upper deck in the picture (circled) of Cathay Pacific Cargo Boeing 747-8F?

Tags: feature-identification, boeing-747

**Cathay Pacific Cargo Boeing 747-8F**

[image]
[Image Source](https://www.airplane-pictures.net/photo/941729/b-ljn-cathay-pacific-cargo-boeing-747-8f/)

**Is that a resting area for pilots or passengers seats?**

Answer (score 11):

What's behind those windows is the crew seating and rest area.

There are no passenger seats on those planes, the seats are specifically for the pilots and the people handling the cargo.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/36349)

Comment: @CarloFelicione why do you think this is not answering the question?

Comment: The original (unedited) answer could possibly have been misinterpreted as re-asking the question, but this seems to be quite clear as an answer now.

Answer (score 4):

Cabin crew and pilot's rest area. Here's a pretty good article that also has videos on the upper deck as well as general cargo plane life [Life on the Upper Deck](https://thepointsguy.com/news/inside-qatar-747-8-freighter/)

Comment: Since this is quite clearly a cargo aircraft (as evidenced by lack of windows at the passenger deck level), and the OP identifies it as a CP _Cargo_ 747-8**F**, there probably aren't a lot of cabin crew needing a rest area for this flight. ;)

Comment: And considering the article states their Cargo plane has a range of 5000 miles, they typically don't fly more than 8 hours. Which wouldn't really warrant a resting crew either. Maybe its more for cargo handlers that might have more legs to their journey?

Comment: I'm pretty sure a primary use is to return *other* crews between flight legs. Deadheading cabin crew on a passenger flight loses you a fare, doing it on a freighter is basically free.